# C- gethostbyaddr & Valgrind

Tags: c, valgrind

For some reason `valgrind` keeps throwing the following error:

```
==6263== Invalid read of size 4
==6263==    at 0x40151B9: (within /lib/ld-2.7.so)
==6263==    by 0x4005C29: (within /lib/ld-2.7.so)
==6263==    by 0x4007A47: (within /lib/ld-2.7.so)
==6263==    by 0x40114F3: (within /lib/ld-2.7.so)
==6263==    by 0x400D585: (within /lib/ld-2.7.so)
==6263==    by 0x4010F0D: (within /lib/ld-2.7.so)
==6263==    by 0x4141391: (within /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.7.so)
==6263==    by 0x400D585: (within /lib/ld-2.7.so)
==6263==    by 0x4141554: __libc_dlopen_mode (in /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.7.so)
==6263==    by 0x411B286: __nss_lookup_function (in /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.7.so)
==6263==    by 0x411B39F: (within /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.7.so)
==6263==    by 0x411CFC5: __nss_hosts_lookup (in /lib/tls/i686/cmov/libc-2.7.so)
==6263==  Address 0x4183d24 is 36 bytes inside a block of size 37 alloc'd
==6263==    at 0x4022AB8: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:207)
```

Here is the way I'm doing it. Any reasons why this is happening? Thanks

```
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

char *IPtoHostname(const char *ipaddress)
{ 
    struct hostent *host;
    unsigned int ip = 0;
    ip = inet_addr (ipaddress);
    host = gethostbyaddr ((char *) &ip, sizeof (unsigned int), AF_INET);
    if (host == NULL) return NULL;
    return strdup(host->h_name);
}

int main () {
   const char *ip = "65.55.4.170";
   char *a =  NULL;
   a = IPtoHostname(ip);
   printf ("%s\n", a); 
   free (a);

   return 0;
}
```

**Update**: It happens when I run it under `Linux hardy 2.6.24-16-generic` It does not happen under `Ubuntu 9.10`

Comment: vg_replace_malloc exists only within valgrind

Comment: You have compiled your program with -O0 -g, right?

Comment: @thkala: I compiled with: `gcc -Wall -O0 -g prog.c`

Comment: Have you installed the debugging symbols for glibc? It would help to pinpoint this issue. Also, what is your valgrind version? I Suspect it is a glibc issue that VG does not have a suppression for, but I'd need a more complete output to make sure.

Comment: No, I have not yet installed the debugging symbols for glibc. Are you referring to `glibc-profile`? Currently I'm using `valgrind-3.3.0-Debian`

Comment: This isn't related to your error, but you should change the parameter `ipaddress` of `IPtoHostname` and the local variable `ip` in `main` to be `const char*` instead of `char*`.  The implicit conversion from string constants to `char*` is deprecated.

Comment: Ok, I managed to reproduce this issue by compiling & trying out valgrind 3.3.0. It does not appear with valgrind versions 3.4.1, 3.5.0 or 3.6.0 on my system so you can safely ignore it. You should really consider upgrading Valgrind though.

Comment: Nonwithstanding the other answers about false valgrind positive/glibc bugs, you should preferably use `getaddrinfo`/`getnameinfo` anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is OK (although you should really be using `in_addr_t` instead of `unsigned int` for the variable `ip` in `IPtoHostname()`).

The Valgrind report is a [well-known issue](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/glibc/+bug/59449) - either a false positive or a bug in glibc.

Answer (score 1):

One way to eliminate the problem in these legacy functions is to stop using them. `gethostbyname` and `gethostbyaddr` have been removed from POSIX as of 2008; they have serious issues with IPv6 support, thread-safety, unclear specification and inconsistent implementation across platforms, and so on. You simply should not use them.

The modern replacements are `getaddrinfo` and `getnameinfo`. If you use these functions, you'll never have to write ugly wrappers like you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

`inet_addr` doesn't always return a simple `unsigned int`.  It returns an `in_addr_t` (or an `in_addr` depending on your flavor of C headers, mine's linux 2.6.31 / glib 2.0).  On my system, `in_addr_t` is actually a 128 bits (16 bytes) because `inet_addr` can return an IPv6 address.

Likewise, `gethostbyaddr` takes an `in_addr_t`, not an `unsigned int`.  This is almost certainly your problem.  Change the type of `ip` to `inet_addr_t` and change the corresponding `sizeof`, and pay more attention to compiler warnings next time.

```
struct hostent *host;
in_addr_t ip = inet_addr(ipaddress);
host = gethostbyaddr (&ip, sizeof(ip), AF_INET);
if (host == NULL) return NULL;
return strdup(host->h_name);
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. However, still the same issue. I'm starting to think it might have something to do with `gethostbyaddr()`

Comment: [POSIX defines `in_addr_t` as](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/basedefs/netinet/in.h.html) *"Equivalent to the type `uint32_t` as defined in `<inttypes.h>` ."*, so if your system does this, then it is not POSIX conforming.  `in_addr_t` is IPv4-specific (as is `inet_addr()`).

Comment: @caf: Indeed. I've never heard of a system with 128-bit `in_addr_t`, and of course it would be non-conformant.

Answer (score -1):

You aren't checking the return value of `gethostbyaddr`. 
What if it returns **NULL** indicating that it was unable to get the host name?
In that case, you try to de-reference **NULL** to call `strdup` on the `host->h_name`.
*That will obviously fail.*

Comment: That's correct, however, I think in this particular case, it will still throw the same error. (checking/not checking for NULL)

Comment: Do you have evidence that gethostbyaddr is NOT failing?  How do you know it is successfully resolving the name if you aren't checking the result?

Comment: You check your return values, I'm too busy downvoting you -.-

Comment: abelenky : It might be failing, but the question is about the valgrind results, which clearly show the problem is happening during host lookup (presumably inside the gethostbyaddr() function).